# Can I receive job alert email weekly, instead of daily?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I have configured a couple of saved searches, and enabled the job alerts email. At the moment I'm receiving a daily email, which seems too much for me.

Is there a way to reduce the frequency of the emails, e.g., receive one mail per week?

From the alerts management page I'm only able to set a daily frequency, or disable the alerts altogether.